# Best way to match values in nested objects JS, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

Ok I have a big JS object that contains data I need within 3 tiers:

```
ob = {
  x1:{
    y11:{a:foo,b:bah},
    y22:{a:foo,b:bah},
    y33:{a:foo,b:bah}
  }
  x2:{
    y11:{a:foo,b:bah},
    y22:{a:foo,b:bah},
    y33:{a:foo,b:bah}
  } 
  x3:{
    y11:{a:foo,b:bah},
    y22:{a:foo,b:bah},
    y33:{a:foo,b:bah}
  }
}
```

I also have an array of values:

```
var array = [foo,bah,foo,bah];
```

I need to check if the values in this array match any of the values at the third tier of my big JS object and pull out some sibling values that i require. I understand this is possible with 3 nested $.each loops. But is that the most efficient way to do this job?

Hope this is clear, appreciate the help!

Comment: unless you have some sort of index that is it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **need** three nested loops to do this. No way around.

```
for(var level1 in ob) {
    for(var entry in level1) {
        for(var value in entry) {
            if( $.inArray(entry[value], array) > -1 ) {
                // match
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this especially taxing with large objects?

Comment: @pagewil: well it depends on how large your objects are, but in general this should be really fast.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am using jQuery $.each instead of for but I'm guessing the performance is very similar.

Comment: @pagewil: `$.each()` will use a `for in` loop itself on objects. So yes performance should be similar, except for a little overhead in calling.